# Accessing Recorder app files

Tags: adb, rooting, android-studio

On my Pixel 4a, I had a number of recordings on the Google Recorder app. When I tried to enable the backup option, something must have gone wrong, and my recordings disappeared from the list, and didn't get backed up either. However I'm sure they are still technically there on the phone, as when I view the app in settings, it has 100mb+ of "user data".

I've read that they're stored in the **/data/data/com.google.android.apps.recorder/files/recordings** folder, but I've been unable to access this file a normal file explorer, or via Android studio (it says run-as: package not debuggable). I've also tried using adb backup, but this produced a 1kb file, so I assume this app has the nobackup option in the manifest file.

Is there any way I can get at these files? I know you can if the phone is rooted, but it isn't, and I believe rooting it involves wiping everything?